# Maximum energy of neutrino from decay of $W$ boson

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, neutrinos, electroweak

Figure 2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.4515.pdf) suggests that neutrinos from the decay of on shell W bosons can have an energy as high as the W boson mass. However, in the $W^{-} \rightarrow e^{-} + \bar{\nu}_{e}$ process, the maximum $\bar{\nu}_{e}$ energy is limited by the mass of electron. Would there be processes allowing such a high energy to the neutrinos?

Comment: Are we in the center of mass frame?

Comment: how then would an electron, for charge and lepton number conservation, be created. Even at rest it needs energy to get its mass.

Comment: Excerpt the graph and your thinking about it which mislead you to read your false summary into it.